# Joomla 1.5 system messages in modal window?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have made a link, that gives me Joomla's registration edit form into a modal window. Everything is okay with this but, when user click on save button, loads the whole homepage in to modal window with a message that says everything saved. How can I make it just load the system message in to modal window and not the whole home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set tmpl=component & format=raw in the controller before calling for the template. Your system msgs div should be inside the component to be shown.

Comment: Do you mean the controller.php file located in /components/com_user folder??? And if yes, where exactly should I set tmpl=component & format=raw??? Thank you!!!

Comment: in the function is being executed before loads the whole homepage in to modal window

Comment: you die; in PHP to find the function. Put die; into each function(one function at a time) and see. if the script stop executing that the function you need to put the code.

Comment: OK I found it... $return = JURI::base(); ...What is the syntax to set tmpl=component & format=raw in to this part of code??? Thank you!!!

Comment: JRequest::setVar( 'tmpl', 'component' );JRequest::setVar( 'format', 'raw' );

Comment: I did this... $return = JRequest::setVar( 'tmpl', 'component' );JRequest::setVar( 'format', 'raw' ); ... And I get this error "The requested URL /site/component was not found on this server."

Comment: this could be due to the seo settings. place in the code at the start of the function

Comment: in the component at the backend you can set the url to whatever you need after registration. set it to hit different task. in the task set a new view only with the msg you want to display

Comment: I did this and it is working!!!... $return = JURI::base().'/index.php?option=com_blahblah&view=account&ml=1'; ...But if I don't put this &ml=1 at the end it loads everything with the home page!!! I don't know what it is, I found it in to an other component!!! Is this correct? And what this &ml=1 means??? Thank you again!!!